# What does the comment "COMBAK" mean?

Tags: vim, comments, todo

I was looking at the vimscript syntax file in the syntax directory, and under the keyword vimTodo were the words `COMBAK`, `FIXME`, `TODO`, and `XXX`. I can figure out what `FIXME` and `TODO` mean pretty easily, and I can guess what some might use `XXX` for, but I have no idea what `COMBAK` is for.

It must have a meaning of some sort, else there would be no reason to highlight it. I get that it's a code tag, but what does it mean? My best guess so far is an abbreviation for COMEBACK, though I doubt this.

Here is what I found so far:

Googling it got me nothing of use, and a google code search for `COMBAK` (with or without the quotes) got 0 results. I eventually Googled `codetag "COMBAK"` and found a single result, which uses it as a tag in a comment twice (a [ctrl+F] will find it): http://pastebin.com/H6mjbyBh.

The program is written in Vimscript, and contains both a vimscript syntax file and vimscript indent plugin file for lisp, along with some other massive functions.

Comment: Yes, it means "COME BACK".

Comment: When would this be used? and is it used frequently? Because I have never seen it before. Does it mean come back and fill in with a code you figure out later? Something else?

Comment: "I have something more urgent to do, let's mark this place so that I can COMBAK to it later." That kind of thing rarely passes the commit stage, though, so it's rare to see it in production/released code. And, with the lightweight branching model available in today's DVCSes, that kind of practice has become kind of irrelevant.

Comment: Quite frankly, the author of this syntax file is known for an ... idiosyncratic programming style (I've heard it described in much harsher words). It is probably best to ignore and avoid this 'COMBAK' altogether.

Comment: @thersawalrus what might some use `XXX` for? what do *you* use it for?

Comment: @chharvey I could see it used as a catchall tag for things that aren't a FIXME (i.e. an error somewhere in the code) and TODO (additional features needed). At least that's how I use those two.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it literally means "COME BACK".

Comment: how would this differ from TODO? Doesn't "to do" also mean "come back"?

Comment: Not getting it. In what context would you want something to "come back"? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: The writer of COME BACK wants himself to come back (because there's something left to do).